# What is the "up-pointing" version of U+25BE?

Tags: unicode

I'm not even sure if it exists but I'm using this Unicode character as a down indicator http://www.charbase.com/25be-unicode-black-down-pointing-small-triangle (▾) but I need the "up" version...any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For this character, http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U25A0.pdf contains U+25BE (▾) and related characters.

Looking at the PDF shows U+25B4 (▴) as the black small up-pointing triangle (formally BLACK UP-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE).

In general, go to http://www.unicode.org/charts and enter the hex number for a character (e.g. 25B4) and it will show you which PDF file describes the related characters.  View the PDF; in this case, a quick scan upwards from the down-pointing arrow found the related character code, and the next page shows the formal name and related details.

Comment: I'll give you the answer for being so thorough, but it looks like there actually isn't a direct relation up-arrow to my down arrow :s

Comment: Perhaps there's something wrong with the font you are using/viewing the characters with.  U+25B4 is the analogous "up" version of U+25BE.  That should be clear from the naming of the two glyphs: "BLACK DOWN-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE" and "BLACK UP-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE".

Comment: In this chart (https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U25A0.pdf), 25B4 matches 25BE. But in multiple apps on my computer, the down arrow renders larger and wider, so they don't look good as a matched pair. Bummer.

Answer (score 14):

U+25B4 (▴) is technically the *up-pointing version* of (▾), but it's not exactly the same.

I was using it for showing whether a dropdown element was open and needed it to be exact. So I ended up using CSS transform to flip it. (In my case *it* was a pseudo-element).

```
.dropdown::after {
  content: '\25BE';
}

.dropdown.active::after {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: I used this technique with a span tag around the down-arrow character, but I had to add `display:inline-block` to rotate the span.

Answer (score 4):

Do you want U+25B4 BLACK UP-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE (▴)?

If you know the codepoint of a character and you're trying to find similar ones, try searching the [code charts](http://www.unicode.org/charts/) by hex code.

Answer (score 1):

U+25B4 = BLACK UP-POINTING SMALL TRIANGLE. Isn't there a character map you can use installed on your system? I have one (gucharmap - the GNOME [Unicode] Character Map) specifically for occasions like this. Just a suggestion. :-)